# Pick-flatten a list

Tags: code-golf, number, array, combinatorics, probability-theory

Consider the process of "picking" a nested list. Picking is defined as follows:

- If the argument is a list, take an element from the list at random (uniformly), and pick from that.
- If the argument is not a list, simply return it.

An example implementation in Python:

```
import random
def pick(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return pick(random.choice(obj))
    else:
        return obj
```

For simplicity, we assume that nested lists only contain integers or further nested lists.

Given any list, it is possible to create a flattened version which is indistinguishable by `pick`, i.e. picking from it yields the same results, with the same probability.

For example, "pick-flattening" the list

```
[1, 2, [3, 4, 5]]
```

yields the list

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

. The reason simply flattening is invalid is because elements of sub-lists have a lower probability of being chosen, e.g. in the list `[1, [2, 3]]` the 1 has a 2/4 = 1/2 chance of being chosen while 3 and 4 both have a 1/4 chance each.

Also note that picking from a singleton list is equivalent to picking from its element, and that picking from an empty list has no meaning.

### The Challenge

Given a nested list of nonnegative integers, return a flattened list of nonnegative integers from which picking yields the same results with the same probability.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid answer (measured in bytes) wins.

### Specifications

- The inputs `[2, 3, 4]`, `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]`, and `[2, [3, 3], [[4]]]` are equivalent (i.e. they should give equivalent results).
- The outputs `[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]` and `[2, 3]` are equivalent (i.e. either one could be output).
- You can assume only numbers in the inclusive range 1-100 will be present in the lists.
- You can assume the top-level input will be a list, i.e. `2` is not a valid input.
- You can use any reasonable representation of nested lists, for example:
  `[1, [2, 3]]`, `1 {2 3}`, `"[ 1 [ 2 3 ] ]"`, etc.
- Instead of a list, you can output a multiset or a mapping, or, since only numbers in the range 1-100 are allowed, a length-100 list of integers representing quantities.

### Test Cases

Note that the listed outputs are only one valid possibility; see specifications for what constitutes a valid input or output.

```
format:
input -> output
[3]                          -> [3]
[1, [1, 1]]                  -> [1]
[1, [2, 3]]                  -> [1, 1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, [4, [5, 5, 6], 6, 7]] -> [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7]
[[1, 1, 2], [2, 3, 3]]       -> [1, 2, 3]
[[1, 1, 2], [2, 3, 3, 3]]    -> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Given the length encoding option and the bounded range, may we alternatively output a list of 100 elements depicting the occurrences of every integer? (which will result with many zeros for the given examples)

Comment: @Uriel Sure; I'll reword it.

Answer (score 8):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>41</s> 20 bytes

```
Flatten@*Tuples//@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n1aaZ/vfLSexpCQ1z0ErpLQgJ7VYX99BWe1/QFFmXomDc35OaW6eW35RbnQ1l4ICUHl0tXFtrA6MbagDRIa1qCJGOsbIIkCuTrWJTrWpjqmOWa2OmY45sixIv45RLVgXqj5UGbAcV23sfwA) Ignore the many warnings, it all works out in the end.

### How it works

For a list of depth 2 such as `{{1,2},{3},{4,5,6}}`, `Tuples` will generate the list `{{1,3,4},{1,3,5},{1,3,6},{2,3,4},{2,3,5},{2,3,6}}` corresponding to all the ways to pick an element from `{1,2}` *and* pick an element from `{3}` *and* pick an element from `{4,5,6}`.

If we `Flatten` this, then we get all the elements with the correct frequencies, because picking an element from *one* of `{1,2}`, `{3}` or `{4,5,6}` is equivalent to picking an element from all of them, then choosing which one to keep.

We use `//@` to apply this at all levels of the input. In the process, Mathematica complains a lot, because it's turning atoms such as `17` into `Tuples[17]`, which is really not supposed to be a thing. But these simplify to the right result later on (`Tuples` is happy to treat `Tuples[17]` as a list of length 1, even if it has a head other than `List`), so the complaining is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>105</s> <s>102</s> 99 bytes

```python
g=lambda y=[],*z:[w+[n]for n in y for w in g(*z)]or[y]
f=lambda x:x<[]and[x]or sum(g(*map(f,x)),[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dUzLDoIwEDzbr9hji3sBfCREvmTdQw0BTaQQxNDy87UF8Wayk8zsPHo33juTed@UT93eKg2uJMZkLmjak@G6G8DAw4CDSKdIG5nMiruBHIt6q9nCXoi1qcgGC17vVoZcq3tZo1UKiZWPCzYuXIWknFEApbgg5Z/KEPJVRRYeh4AjQrgTByCcV3vpIWSMWzT/a3w9VYhdPzzMCLW0yn8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ß€Œp$¬¡F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w/EdNa45OKlA5tObQQrf/h9uBXPf//zWijWN1uBSiDXXA2DAWzjPSUTCG8EAsoIAJEJvqKACRWSwQ6yiYQ6TB@nQUjGJ1YEqNcUpA5TQB)

#### How it works

```
ß€Œp$¬¡F  Main link. Argument: x (array or positive integer)

     ¬    Compute elementwise logical NOT of x: a non-empty array for a non-empty array, 0 for a positive integer.
      ¡   Apply the link to the left once if ¬ returned a non-empty
          array, zero timed if it returned 0.
    $     Monadic chain:
ß€            Map the main link over x.
  Œp          Take the Cartesian product.
       F  Flatten the result.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
L€P⁸ṁ€ẎµÐL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/nUdOagEeNOx7ubASyHu7qO7T18ASf/4fbj056uHPG///R0YY6CkBkFKujEG2ko2AMRLGxAA)

Comment: @Challenger5 sorry, no time for that yesterday

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 128 bytes

```python
def f(l,p=0):m=reduce(int.__mul__,[i*0<[]or len(i)for i in l]);return p*(p==l)or f(sum([(([i],i)[i*0>0]*m)[:m]for i in l],[]),l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc3NDgIhDATgV@HYbhqzP7dVfJGm4eBCbAJIcDn49Ig3b5OZfJnyOZ@vvPZ@@GACRCp2xj3Z6o/28KD5vDiXWnSOWKf5xvKqJvoMimEkNZpNFLxWf7aaTZmgWBtxTAHeLQEDsAop/vR9likh70n@LLEgReyljrOhmBdaaB39ShttIti/)

Port of my Jelly answer.

-12 thanks to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech).

Comment: I think `type(i)==int` can be `i*0<[]`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Sure, `0<[]`...and `type(i)==list` can be `i*0>0` ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>234</strike> 223 bytes

```c
h[9][101];o[101];n[9];l;L;e;main(x){for(;(x=scanf("%d",&e))>=0;x?++h[l][e],++n[l]:(e=getchar())-'['?e-']'?0:--l:++l>L&&++L);for(e=1,l=L+1;l--;){for(x=101;--x;o[x]+=e*h[l][x]);e*=n[l];}while(o[x]--?printf("%d ",x):++x<101);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5RasMwEESvIgy1tVkv2G2TUm8VX8A3EPow6iY2qEpxAxWUnN2Vk69ZZmHe83T2fl0n@@5s27SOL4@IueDAAwt/jXPUCf5Ol0WzTubHj/Gki6fPoi4F4GgaTj3iZIOz4mrEmK9OiznL1U/jogGoslUvVLmqbzqi0CGG41CWiAPwtiumrYMZsOVAxA9WMtmEiVJ2Sg6N7O6I5IBlZzYI336nOYje/kT99zLH691MFXWCDEkfeQL4tq7P6kXZV2X3aq8OTh3Um/sH)

**Explanation:**

```c
h[9][101];  // <- number occurences per nesting level
o[101];     // <- number occurences in "flattened" array
n[9];       // <- number of entries per nesting level
l;          // <- current nesting level
L;          // <- max nesting level
e;          // <- multi-purpose temporary
main(x){    // x: multi-purpose temporary
    for(;
            // while not EOF try reading number
            (x=scanf("%d",&e))>=0;

            // number was read?
            x

                // then increment occurence and # entries in level
                ?++h[l][e],++n[l]

                // else read any character ... if not [
                :(e=getchar())-'['

                    // if not ]
                    ?e-']'

                        // do nothing
                        ?0

                        // else decrement nesting level
                        :--l

                    // else increment nesting level and adjust max level
                    :++l>L&&++L);

    // init factor in e to 1, iterate over nesting level from innermost
    for(e=1,l=L+1;l--;){

        // iterate over all numbers
        for(x=101;
                --x;

                // add factor times occurence on current level to output
                o[x]+=e*h[l][x]);

        // multiply factor by number of entries on current level
        e*=n[l];
    }

    // iterate over all numbers and output count times
    while(o[x]--?printf("%d ",x):++x<101);
}
```

Comment: [216 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY5RasMwEESvIgw12qwXoqZJsbeqL@AbCH0YdRMbVKW4gQpKe3VXTr9mmGVnXqBLCOs6udY7szeer/@SSsCRBxZ@H@ekM3yfr4vmX53tZxjTWVcPb1VTCwDnHnFy0TvxDWIqrtNiL3IL07hoAGpNL9Qe@n1HFDvE@DrUNeIAvHWKNU20AxqORCw7uzXAdsm2sDBRLlTZo5XdfSZ74K9pjqK3mKj/WOZ0uxOpqslQFvJL@QT@WddHdVDuSbmjOqqTVyf17P8A "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>144</s> 139 bytes

```python
def f(A,p):[F.append((len(A)*p,a))if a*0<[]else f(a,len(A)*p)for a in A]
F=[];f(input(),1);R=[]
for v in F:R+=max(F)[0]/v[0]*[v[1]]
print R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY/RToQwEEXf@YpJfWmx6gKrm4CYEBI@gNemD43bZptgt1kR16/HAcGQKBtt7jRpe2Z6r/9oD0cX92VOCOn32oChBfcsFdWt8l67PaWNdrRgoeeKMWtAhZtHIXXzqpFVfH5l5ngCBdZBIYMqFzIz1Dr/1lLGI5bVeBMMSDcgVVpf5y/qTCsmNvKuwy0UnYikDPzJuhbqHv1k@qyfyfvBNhrKdDhASXqRSFhdVzdPgEAgIg5D4cQVKJqgmEOyDuEEDiMSjCQ2bLHuOaAeJBaHHbaPdDyil5X8QdtZ0zcL7b6EbmZvcsqwjDF7n4z/gn7Ti5g/9b8E8hM)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>132</s> 131 bytes

```
f=A=>(_=(a,m)=>[].concat(...a.map(m)),n=1,A=A.map(a=>a.map?f(a):[a]),_(A,a=>n*=a.length),_(A,a=>_(a.map(x=>Array(n/a.length).fill(x)))))
```

```js
f=A=>(_=(a,m)=>[].concat(...a.map(m)),n=1,A=A.map(a=>a.map?f(a):[a]),_(A,a=>n*=a.length),_(A,a=>_(a,x=>Array(n/a.length).fill(x))))

console.log( f( [3] ) )
console.log( f( [1, [1, 1]] ) )
console.log( f( [1, [2, 3]] ) )
console.log( f( [2, 3, [4, [5, 5, 6], 6, 7]] ) )
console.log( f( [[1, 1, 2], [2, 3, 3]] ) )
console.log( f( [[1, 1, 2], [2, 3, 3, 3]] ) )
console.log( f( [1, 2, [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]] ) )
```